# set img as value for input type='text'?

Tags: javascript

```html
<input type='text' id='txt'>
<input type='button' id='btn' onclick='upv()' value='01'>
<script>
function upv()
{
 document.getElementById("txt").value +="<IMG SRC='pics/smile/01.png'>";
}
</script>
```

I am trying to make a function with js, it means that if a user clicks on an image , make input `value+= 'img'', I tried it with different ways and can't do it!

can any one suggest a solution?

Comment: Please add a code snippet of your attempt so far. Stackoverflow isn't just a place where people do all your work for you.

Comment: Please show us what you have tried so far yourself

Comment: please add some code so can help you better bro

Comment: i will update it now

Comment: So the problem is: I want the `input`'s value to be changed when user clicks on any `img` on the page. Am I right?

Comment: yea and this clicked img added to the input's value !

Comment: To clarify. You want the input's value to be some text or what?

Comment: Try below: function upv()
{ var tmp =document.getElementById("txt").value;
 document.getElementById("txt").value =tmp + "<IMG SRC='pics/smile/01.png'>";
}

Comment: guys like if input's value ='some text ' and user clickedon  img '01.png' so input's value will be 'some text +this img'

Comment: Ok, I think I know what are you trying to achieve. You want to set the input's value as the actual image. Not the path, not the name. THE IMAGE. This is the reason why we can't understand you. Let me explain that to you. It is NOT possible since it's **text** input

Comment: thx @SebastianKaczmarek for your explain , btw sorry for the stupid ask.

Answer (score 0):

You Can Get Image Name By using following Function

```
function getName() {
 var fullPath = document.getElementById("img1").src;
 var filename = fullPath.replace(/^.*[\\\/]/, '');
 // or, try this, 
 // var filename = fullPath.split("/").pop();

document.getElementById("result").value = filename;}
```